# Problem when inserting a sublayer below an existing layer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I'm trying to add a sublayer behind an existing layer in Swift, but the sublayer is still coming up in front of the existing layer - I must have a problem in my code;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let mainView = UIView()
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let focusBG = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    view.addSubview(mainView)
    mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 325).isActive = true
    mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ((325 / 9) * 16)).isActive = true
    mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    mainView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    let tapView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 150, height: 200))
    tapView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    mainView.addSubview(tapView)

    focusBG.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    focusBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 0.0, alpha: 0.4)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(focusBG.layer, below: tapView.layer)
}

}
```

Ideally the red box would be in front of the greyed out layer - but this is what i am getting;
[image: screenshot1]

Thanks!

**Update: Working Code**

```
        self.mainView.insertSubview(focusBG, belowSubview: tapView)

    focusBG.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    focusBG.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    focusBG.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    focusBG.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth).isActive = true
    focusBG.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
self.mainView.insertSubview(focusBG, belowSubiew: tapView)
```

Or

```
self.mainView.layer.insertSublayer(focusBG.layer, below: tapView.layer) // not tested
```

Comment: thanks this code got it working, i just had to position it back to center with constraints;
`self.mainView.insertSubview(focusBG, belowSubview: tapView)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `insertSublayer`, method works for me.

`self.mainView.layer.insertSublayer(your_Layer, at: 1) // 1 is the position of the layer you want to add to the mainView.`

Thanks and let me know if this works for you. Dont Forget to upvote if it does ;)